# Is there a way to fetch an API with endpoints from user input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, client-side

I suck at explaining this. So, basically, I'm making an another coronavirus tracker and I want users to be able to type their country's name in a form ("search box" to make it simpler to understand). After pressing enter, data will be fetched from an API with jQuery like this: `https://api.covid19api.com/country/<USER_INPUT>` and the data will be shown on the website. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you already has an API service available  https://api.covid19api.com/country/<USER_INPUT> you can use JQuery GET method to get data.

Comment: You can find documentation for Get method in JQuery here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, check here how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question is very broad - what have you tried already and where are you stuck?

Comment: smh, ya'll didn't understand my question.    the idea was to       fetch some data based      on  user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API supports CORS, sure. Run the snippet to see a POC.

```js
async function search() {
  const country = document.getElementById("country").value.trim();
  if(!country) return alert("Enter a country.");
  const url = `https://api.covid19api.com/country/${country}`;
  try {
    document.getElementById("output").value = "Fetching...";
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if(!res.ok) throw new Error("Result not OK");
    const data = await res.json();
    document.getElementById("output").value = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="search(); event.preventDefault(); return false">
  <label>Country: <input type=search placeholder="Country code (e.g. FI)" id="country"></label>
  <button type=submit>Search</button>
</form>
<hr />
<textarea readonly id="output" rows=10 placeholder="Results appear here"></textarea>
```